# cilk++ on linux system

Tags: linux, cilk, cilk-plus

I had some problems with a cilk++ program that works well on windows system but not on linux system:

on windows system, while increasing the number of threads the execution time decrease
but on linux system, while increasing the number of threads the execution time increase.

I used linux ubuntu 2.6.35-22-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux

I can't understand the source of the problem.So can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Without sources, there's no way to know.  There may be a resource that has a per-thread implementation on Windows and a shared implementation on Linux.

I'd recommend using a performance analyzer like Intel's VTune/Amplifier to figure out where your application is spending it's time.

```
- Barry Tannenbaum
  Intel Cilk Plus Runtime Development
```